# How does the __getitem__'s idx work within PyTorch's DataLoader?

Tags: python, pytorch, dataloader

I'm currently trying to use PyTorch's DataLoader to process data to feed into my deep learning model, but am facing some difficulty.

The data that I need is of shape `(minibatch_size=32, rows=100, columns=41)`. The `__getitem__` code that I have within the custom `Dataset` class that I wrote looks something like this:

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    x = np.array(self.train.iloc[idx:100, :])
    return x
```

The reason I wrote it like that is because I want the DataLoader to handle input instances of shape `(100, 41)` at a time, and we have 32 of these single instances.

However, I noticed that contrary to my initial belief the `idx` argument the DataLoader passes to the function is not sequential (this is crucial because my data is time series data). For example, printing the values gave me something like this:

```
idx = 206000
idx = 113814
idx = 80597
idx = 3836
idx = 156187
idx = 54990
idx = 8694
idx = 190555
idx = 84418
idx = 161773
idx = 177725
idx = 178351
idx = 89217
idx = 11048
idx = 135994
idx = 15067
```

Is this normal behavior? I'm posting this question because the data  batches that are being returned are not what I initially wanted them to be.

The original logic that I used to preprocess the data before using the DataLoader was:

1. Read data in from either `txt` or `csv` file.
2. Calculate how many batches are in the data and slice the data accordingly. For example, since one input instance is of shape `(100, 41)` and 32 of these form one minibatch, we usually end up with around 100 or so batches and reshape the data accordingly.
3. One input is of shape `(32, 100, 41)`.

I'm not sure how else I should be handling the DataLoader hook methods. Any tips or advice are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your `2`?  "we usually end up with around 100" do you mean your dataset has 32*100 sample?

Comment: Hi. No, I mean that one input to the model is of shape `(100, 40)`, and there are 32 of those that form one minibatch.

Comment: @Seankala I tried to walk you through the DataLoader code. Let me know if that was helpful.

Comment: @Berriel Yes, it helped a lot. Thanks so much for taking the time and effort for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What defines the idx is the `sampler` or `batch_sampler`, as you can see [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/e870a9a87042805cd52973e36534357f428a0748/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py#L207-L219) (open-source projects are your friend). In this [code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/e870a9a87042805cd52973e36534357f428a0748/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py#L285-L294) (and comment/docstring) you can see the difference between `sampler` and `batch_sampler`. If you look [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/e870a9a87042805cd52973e36534357f428a0748/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py#L344-L349) you'll see how the index is chosen:

```py
def __next__(self):
    index = self._next_index()

# and _next_index is implemented on the base class (_BaseDataLoaderIter)
def _next_index(self):
    return next(self._sampler_iter)

# self._sampler_iter is defined in the __init__ like this:
self._sampler_iter = iter(self._index_sampler)

# and self._index_sampler is a property implemented like this (modified to one-liner for simplicity):
self._index_sampler = self.batch_sampler if self._auto_collation else self.sampler
```

Pay attention that this is the `_SingleProcessDataLoaderIter` implementation; you can find the `_MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter` [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/e870a9a87042805cd52973e36534357f428a0748/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py#L823-L840) (ofc, which one is used depends on the `num_workers` value, as you can see [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/e870a9a87042805cd52973e36534357f428a0748/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py#L274-L278)). Going back to the samplers, assuming your Dataset is not `_DatasetKind.Iterable` and that you are not providing a custom sampler, it means you are either using ([dataloader.py#L212-L215](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/e870a9a87042805cd52973e36534357f428a0748/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py#L212-L215)):

```py
if shuffle:
    sampler = RandomSampler(dataset)
else:
    sampler = SequentialSampler(dataset)

if batch_size is not None and batch_sampler is None:
    # auto_collation without custom batch_sampler
    batch_sampler = BatchSampler(sampler, batch_size, drop_last)
```

Let's take a look at [how the default BatchSampler builds a batch](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/e870a9a87042805cd52973e36534357f428a0748/torch/utils/data/sampler.py#L166-L212):

```py
def __iter__(self):
    batch = []
    for idx in self.sampler:
        batch.append(idx)
        if len(batch) == self.batch_size:
            yield batch
            batch = []
    if len(batch) > 0 and not self.drop_last:
        yield batch
```

Very simple: it gets indices from the sampler until the desired batch_size is reached.

Now the question "How does the __getitem__'s idx work within PyTorch's DataLoader?" can be answered by seeing how each default sampler works.

- [SequentialSampler](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/e870a9a87042805cd52973e36534357f428a0748/torch/utils/data/sampler.py#L51-L65) (this is the full implementation -- very simple, isn't it?):

```py
class SequentialSampler(Sampler):
    def __init__(self, data_source):
        self.data_source = data_source

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(range(len(self.data_source)))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data_source)
```

- [RandomSampler](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/e870a9a87042805cd52973e36534357f428a0748/torch/utils/data/sampler.py#L68-L110) (let's see only the `__iter__` implementation):

```py
def __iter__(self):
    n = len(self.data_source)
    if self.replacement:
        return iter(torch.randint(high=n, size=(self.num_samples,), dtype=torch.int64).tolist())
    return iter(torch.randperm(n).tolist())
```

Therefore, as you did not provide any code, we can only assume:

1. You are using `shuffle=True` in your DataLoader **or**
2. You are using a custom sampler **or**
3. Your Dataset is `_DatasetKind.Iterable`

Comment: a brilliant answer!