# Does pytorch Dataset.__getitem__ have to return a dict?

Tags: python, pytorch

EDIT:  This is not about the general `__getitem__` method but the usage of `__getitem__` in the Pytorch Dataset-subclass, as @dataista correctly states.

I'm trying to implement the usage of Pytorchs Dataset-class.
The guide e.g [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html) is really good, but I struggle to figure out Pytorch requirements for the return value of `__getitem__`. In the [Pytorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset) I cannot find anything about what it should return; is it any object which is iterable with size 2 e.g `[sample,target], (sample,target)`? In some guides they return a dict, but they do not specify if it *has* to be a dict which is returned.

Comment: The return value can be anything (not necessarily dict or tuple).

Comment: I have made an edit to the question to clarify

Comment: You can return whatever you want, In most cases you just return the data and the targets for example like this ```return images, targets```

Comment: @CutePoison `__getitem__` in PyTorch DataSets _is_ the general `__getitem__` - there is nothing special about it.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, since Pytorch's dataset `__getitem__` has some particularities. The duplicate flag should be removed.

Comment: This is indeed a question that should be answered on its own. The pytorch framework requires one to implement the `__getitem__` method as part of the abstract `Dataset` base class. As such, it is a valid question _what exactly is the contract of `__getitem__` within the pytorch framework_? The linked answer doesn't address that at all. It is just a coincidence that pytorch doesn't seem to have any / much requirements on the return type.

Comment: Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58834338/how-does-the-getitem-s-idx-work-within-pytorchs-dataloader >> Contains useful (to me) references to the sections of code that determine how a batch is put together, given sampler and dataset type. Seems like (?) the batch is just a list of what's returned by `__getitem__` in this case. To directly return batches, you could implement `__getitems__` ([reference](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset) ).

Answer (score 3):

PyTorch has no requirements on the return value of a DataSet's `__getitem__` method. It can be anything, but you will commonly encounter a tensor, a tuple of tensors, a dictionary (e.g. `{'features':..., 'label':...}`) etc.

It is usual in 2d data to return a single tensor whose final column are the target values, but equally you may see tuples/dicts of the features and targets explicitly separated.

Note there is no requirement that you return two values - in many unsupervised contexts (e.g. autoencoders) there is only a set of features, with no distinct target.