# Why does Pytorch DataLoader output a list?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

So as I was programming and skimming through the pytorch docs, I stumbled across DataLoader. I learnt a fair bit and continued researching, and then saw a comment on a youtube video covering it, stating that DataLoader actually outputs a list instead of a tensor.

I then used the type() on the iterable data and learnt that this was true, could anyone please help me understand why the DataLoader outputs a list instead of a tensor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is PyTorch Dataset supposed to return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72867109/what-is-pytorch-dataset-supposed-to-return)

Comment: Sorry, @Bhargav it didn't, but appreciate the gesture

Comment: check the first answer

Comment: pls post the piece of code you trying. That would be helpful to asses the question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The pytorch `DataLoader` class has a `collate_fn` that processes dataset items into a batch. Using the example from the [pytorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html), it works like this:

```py
for indices in batch_sampler:
    yield collate_fn([dataset[i] for i in indices])
```

If you don't pass a `collate_fn`, pytorch automatically uses `default_collate`. The behavior of `default_collate` depends on the types from you dataset, defined [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.default_collate).